# Rabbitmq consumer become 0 after a period

Tags: go, rabbitmq

I am newbie for rabbitmq.

For example, there has a queue call queue A and it is running. When a request coming, it return the response. After a week, theres no response return . When checking, I found the consumer auto become 0 and need manually rerun the queue, why the consumer become 0 after a week and how can solve this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

With github.com/streadway/amqp, you can use conn.NotifyClose(closeNotify) to get a chan to handle connection error. For example, you can create a goroutine to handle reconnection like this:

```
for {
    select {
    case <-closeNotify:
        //reconnect and get closeNotify for the new connection
        //send the new amqp.Connection to other goroutine 
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return
    }
}
```

amqp.Channel also provide the same feature for AMQP Channel level error.

BTW, it is recommended to create seperate amqp.Channels in each goroutine and share a amqp.Connection within a process.